# Script to rename active sheet like the spreadsheet name

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

is there a script that rename an already existing sheet with the name of the spreadsheet?
I've searched around but couldn't find any solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function renameSheet() {
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName()
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().setName(name)
}
```